# Can a demon open the physical eyes of the blind?

Tags: john

John 10:21

> But others said, “These are not the sayings of a man possessed by a demon. Can a demon open the eyes of the blind?”

Can it?

Comment: Is there any documented evidence that this has ever occurred ?  _Since the world began was it not heard that any man opened the eyes of one that was born blind._ John 9:32.

Comment: The point of that verse being someone *born* blind rather than becoming blind. The latter can be cured even with things like cataract surgery that was known to the Romans or in some cases even vitamin deficiencies. But someone who never had sight from birth is a different matter.

Answer (score 3):

> 19 There was a division therefore again among the Jews for these
> sayings.
> 20 **And many of them said, He hath a devil, and is mad; why hear ye
> him**?
> 21 **Others said, These are not the words of him that hath a devil. Can
> a devil open the eyes of the blind?**

Group (A); believes he has a devil, why even listen to him!
Group (B); Then gives group (A) a rhetorical question, can a devil open the eyes of the blind? The answer that they can't and so He can't have a devil in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

We are not told explicitly the answer to this question.  However, I think we can at least provide a partial answer to the question with the following caveat: The Bible makes it very plain that the powers of darkness, including Stan's minions are capable of performing some miracles in order to deceive the wicked.  See appendix below.

However, my personal view, is that such deceiving signs and wonders are definitely limited in their scope.  For example, God alone is the creator (Isa 44:24, 45:18 John 1:3, 10, Col 1:16, 17, Heb 1:2) and the creator of life.  Therefore, while Satan might well be able to do a good impression of creating life, I do not believe it is possible for him to actually create life.

The rhetorical question of the Jewish leaders appears to confirm that they believed the same thing.  The Pulpit commentary observes:

> **Can a daemon open the eyes of the blind?** It is not in the nature of a damon to heal disease, and pour light on sightless eyes. The
> goodness of the Lord triumphs over the vile insinuation. We must have
> better explanation than this of his mysterious claims. The contest was
> sharp. The conflict for a while silenced opposition, only to break out
> again with greater malice and fury. John 10:21

In commenting on John 9:16, Ellicott says this:

> Others said, How can a man that is a sinner do such miracles?—This
> question is asked by the better party among the Pharisees,
> represented, as we know, by Nicodemus and Joseph of Arimathæa, and
> perhaps by Gamaliel. They see the inference implied in the earlier
> question, and appeal to the nature of the miracles wrought. Works of
> mercy, and love, and power, were not the product of a life of sin, or
> of communion with the powers of darkness. We find evidence of this
> better spirit among the Pharisees before, in the question of Nicodemus
> (John 7:51). It has now extended to others. The teaching on the
> earlier work on the Sabbath (John 5) has led some among them, at
> least, to look with allowance upon this.

**APPENDIX - False or Lying Signs and Wonders**

Pseudo (false) signs and wonders are invariably produced in order to deceive the wicked.

- Matt 24:24, Mark 13:22 predict false signs and wonders performed by false Christs and false prophets
- 2 Thess 2:9 predicts the rise of the lawless one accompanied by false signs and wonders
- Rev 16:14 predicts that demons will perform false signs and wonders
- Rev 13:13, 14 19:20 predict that the great false prophet (third beast of the Beast Trinity) will perform false signs and wonders

It should be remembered that Deut 13:1-5 contains a stern warning about the veracity of signs and wonders to see if they are genuine.  Similarly, Matt 24:24 contains Jesus’ warning not to base one’s faith purely on Signs and Wonders.

Answer (score 1):

Demons have a few sleight-of-hand style tricks up their sleeves.  They can make it *appear* that they restore sight.  It can seem like a genuine healing.  But in reality, what the demons did was *cause the blindness* first, then they simply remove what they themselves caused and, voila!  It looks like a real healing!

Being "healed" by a demon is risky...the healing may not last long.  Especially is this true when the "healing" is performed by a spiritualist, witch doctor, medicine man, shaman, etc. who is serving the demons and gathers an income from the healing services provided to others.

Yes, demons can make it *appear* that miracles have occurred.  Let us not forget their magic tricks in Egypt with Moses before Pharaoh (see Exodus 7:8-12, 22; 8:7; etc.).

And Satan will even make fire come down from heaven:

> And he doeth great wonders, so that he maketh fire come down from
> heaven on the earth in the sight of men,  And deceiveth them that
> dwell on the earth by the means of **those miracles which he had power
> to do** in the sight of the beast; saying to them that dwell on the
> earth, that they should make an image to the beast, which had the
> wound by a sword, and did live.  (Revelation 13:13-14)

Notice that the Bible addresses both miracles that are feigned, as were those apparently life-creating "enchantments" done in Egypt, and miracles that "he had power to do."  There are some miracles which Satan can really do--and he will do them to deceive us.

Answer (score 1):

I’d argue that this question can only be answered via conjecture - nevertheless I will use this to present an answer for consideration

My answer is categorically no! And the reason is, a ‘demon’ is a spirit, and a ‘spirit’ can do nothing unless it has a ‘body’ to use. Everyone needs a [physical] body in order to do anything, in order to interact with this ‘world’.

**MAT 12:43** *When an unclean spirit goes out of a man, he goes through dry places, seeking rest, and finds none.* **44** *Then he says, ‘I will return to my house from which I came*[snip]

So , maybe the question should be whether anyone has *used* ‘demonic’ power to open eyes?

A key point of claim. Your quote from John 10 relates to an incident in John 9....

**JOHN 9:32***Since the world began it has been unheard of that anyone opened the eyes of one who was born blind.*

You need to understand that this is referring to a man **born** blind. And it was prophesied that only the Messiah could do this - as it was documented that the Rabbis could/did at times open blind eyes. This is important to keep in mind because this *backgrounds* the context to the verse you used in your question.

This incident was one of three clear Messianic signs that [only] the coming Messiah would be able to perform. And here someone had performed it. And it was this that caused the division or ‘arguing’ that backgrounds your verse ..

**JOHN 10:21** *Others said, “These are not the words of one who has a demon. Can a demon open the eyes of the blind?”*

The Pharisees **had to** provide an explanation - one other than agreeing that this *was* the Messiah. And they used the ‘fallback’ answer ‘he did this via demonic power’, as no one could argue against this - except the Jews **knew** that it *couldn’t* be a demon.

And that is the exactly the same answer to your Q, that although we can’t (hermeneutically) argue or prove the case, but we all *know* it wasn’t a ‘demon’ - because that’s not possible.

Answer (score 1):

***Can a demon open the eyes of the blind?***

Short Answer: **No**.

When we look to the blind man (blind from birth) in John's Gospel (chapter 9), we read something very relevant to this discussion:

> **John 9:30-33**: "The [blind] man answered and said to [the Pharisees]… We know that God does not hear sinners; but if anyone is God-fearing and does His will, He hears him. *Since the beginning of time it has never been heard that anyone opened the eyes of a person born blind*. If this man were not from God, He could do nothing.'"

Would God allow anything untrue to be entered into the Holy Record? (Of course, we might speculate that God did allow demons the ability to heal those *not* blind from birth, but I can find no evidence to that effect.)

It was certainly the case that demons were capable of some types of miracles (Ex. 7:11-12 , 1 Sam. 28:12, etc.). And, few would deny that dark forces operate all over the globe, often with the intent to destroy us. Is a terrorist bent on murdering as many innocent men, women, and children, as possible not indoctrinated by some form of demonic influence?

What may not be so obvious is what the apostle Paul warns about:

> **1 Timothy 4:1**: "But the Spirit explicitly says that in later times some will fall away from the faith, *paying attention to deceitful spirits and doctrines of demons*"

*Very strong words by Paul*.

The passage above indicates that not only were demons active in malevolent practices, but they are also the spiritual force behind those who teach false doctrine — doctrines of demons. They are, even now, perpetuating demonic fabrications and lies, and these emerge when we least expect them.

The Bible speaks of "ravenous wolves" and "wolves in sheep's clothing":

> **Matthew 7:15**: "“Beware of the false prophets, who come to you in sheep’s clothing, but inwardly are ravenous wolves."

Who are these "wolves" exactly? Well, we should understand that *all false teaching* falls into this category, whether it be "merely" deceitful preaching — something very subtle, or flagrant occult spiritism — the far more obvious, and that which is in alignment with the question asked in the OP.

For example, who has not read a horoscope or other, similar occult tendencies and not found certain *truths* behind them? In fact, if they had absolutely *no truth* whatsoever, such practices would probably never have seen the light of day. It is because they *do* possess certain truths that we should recognize them for what they are and avoid them.

Israel received a stern warning about such things from God:

> **Deuteronomy 18:10-11**: "There shall not be found among you anyone who makes his son or his daughter pass through the fire [burning children alive], one who uses divination, one who practices witchcraft, or one who interprets omens, or a sorcerer, or one who casts a spell, or a medium, or a spiritist, or one who calls up the dead."

These passages *confirm* that demons had such abilities. Otherwise, God would not have warned them about it because they would not have been endowed with any efficacious qualities.

Despite certain, limited miracles by demons of the O/T, **they have never been able to open the eyes of the blind** (Jn. 9:33, 10:21). Nonetheless, that does not release us from great vigilance against the dark forces of the world around us.

Answer (score 1):

The question “Can a demon open the eyes of the blind?” was prompted by Jesus’ healing of the man born blind in John 9. What is fascinating about this story is how it interweaves the concepts of physical and spiritual blindness. On one level it is a story about Jesus’ healing of the man’s physical blindness. On another level, the story juxtaposes the insight that the blind man gains against the spiritual blindness in which the Pharisees choose to obstinately remain.

> Jesus heard that they had put him out, and upon finding him, He said,
> “Do you believe in the Son of Man?” 36 He answered by saying, “And who
> is He, Sir, that I may believe in Him?” 37 Jesus said to him, “You
> have both seen Him, and He is the one who is talking with you.” 38 And
> he said, “I believe, Lord.” And he worshiped Him. 39 And Jesus said,
> “For judgment I came into this world, so that those who do not see may
> see, and those who see may become blind.” 40 Those who were with Him
> from the Pharisees heard these things and said to Him, “We are not
> blind too, are we?” 41 Jesus said to them, “If you were blind, you
> would have no sin; but now that you maintain, ‘We see,’ your sin
> remains. - Jn 9:35-41

“Can a demon open the eyes of the blind?” Spiritually speaking, it is both impossible and illogical (Mt 12:25, Jn 8:44). Physically speaking, if the the blind man did indeed receive spiritual insight, the answer is also no.

> If this man were not from God, He could do nothing.” - Jn 9:33